# How can I test an object to see if it is an int with a value of 3?

Tags: c#

I have C# method:

```
public class HeaderType1BoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = value as int;
        var ret = (s == 3);
        return !ret;
    }

}
```

What I need to do is to take that object (which will be an integer), check if its value is 3 and if so return true.  Otherwise if it's null or not equal to 3 then I want to return false.

But I am having a problem as it says that

> Error CS0077: The as operator must be used with a reference type or
>   nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type) (CS0077) (Japanese)

Can someone give me advice on how I can do this check?

Comment: Why you're using `as` if you know it's an int ? Also, the exception is straight forward you use `as` operator to do `try to convert` since we don't know what the object might be, weather it has a `try to convert method` there's the `as` operator, however int has a `tryparse` emthod, which you can use.

Comment: What about using the `is` operator to check the type of `value`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return object.Equals(value, 3);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark,  Will this return false if the value is null?

Comment: Yes. Be careful though, it will also return false if you pass in any non-null value that isn't an integer 3 (e.g. a double).

Comment: And it has to be `Int32`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use "as" for int, because it is value type. 
You can use nullable type with "as":

```
var s = value as int?;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have done some wrong things in your code here is the fixed code to what do you want:-

```
public class HeaderType1BoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = 0;
        try{ s = (int)value; }catch(Exception e){ return false; }
        return s != 3;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

**first** is the most straight forward:

```
try
{
  string x = "text or int";
  int num = Convert.ToInt32(x);
  Console.WriteLine("this num is an int: " + num);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine("this num is not an int");
}
```

**method 2** with `GetType()` method and `typeof()` method:

```
private bool isNumber(object p_Value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (int.Parse(p_Value.ToString()).GetType().Equals(typeof(int)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use following tested code that eliminate your error.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (System.Convert.ToInt32(value)==3);
    }
```